# scene graph, shared pointers and constness propagation

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, smart-pointers

I am working on an existing large project which basically:

- Uses a scene graph, where each node has children slots
- Performs an initialization step where each node recursively initializes its children, and do some precalc/cleanup tasks on its own data members.
- Then a large computation is started, the scene graph is then accessed in pure read-only mode from const member functions only

Currently, children are stored using smart pointers, mostly to avoid deep copies when building the graph from file read and during user edition of the graph.

As the smart pointers (std::shared_ptr) do not propagate constness, I have the following options:

1. Store the children using **smart pointers to const objects**. When
   recursively doing the initialization step, **const_cast** them to
   non-const pointers Store the children using smart pointers to const
   objects. For recursively doing the initialization step, const_cast
   them to non-const pointers. I do not like abusing of const_cast
2. Store the children using **smart pointers to const objects**. When
   recursively doing the initialization step, do a **deep copy** of each children to a non-const object, initialize it, and replace the children by the initialized one. This is not efficient, each node is deep-copied during initialization
3. Store the children using **smart pointers to non-const objects**. Then initialization is not a problem anymore, but all const member functions used during computation may call non const member functions of children, which is a potential source of bugs and clearly non const-correct.

I know that using smart pointers only to avoid deep copies during tree manipulation is not the nice way to implement this at the age of c++11 and move semantics. Rewriting all the code with move semantics might be done one day, but this represents quite a large work.

What would be, in your opinion, the nicest way to implement that pattern, without rewriting all with move semantics? I have thought of wrapping std::shared_ptr to propagate constness, are there other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using raw pointers? Probably, in your data structure, the only changes should be in node destructor (to delete all children) and node removal method (to delete the node being removed). However, if things are more complicated than what I think, then make the wrapper.

Comment: @AndreSassi Raw pointers will not propagate constness any better than smart-pointers. Also using raw pointers is going to make life difficult especially with node copying behaviour.

Comment: *"As the smart pointers (std::shared_ptr) do not propagate constness"* You can do that manually, if those smart pointers are not public data members: don't modify the object pointed to in `const` member functions (and don't provide non-const access to that object in `const` member functions).

Comment: @dyp : yes, but mistakes are always possible, such as calling a non-const member function of a child. And the compiler won't complain. The whole purpose of constness is lost if you have to manually think about not doing non-const operations in const functions

Comment: You can wrap the smart pointer in a class that provides "deep constness"..

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 3 but store the children in private member variables in a base class or composed object.

Only allow access to the children via getters that enforce const correctness.

The const getter returning a raw pointer-to-const.  The non-const getter returning a raw pointer or shared pointer.

Something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<class Child>
class Parent {
 private: 
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Child>> children_;
 protected:
  ~Parent() = default;
 public:
  const Child* getChild(size_t child_number) const { 
    return children_.at(child_number).get(); 
  } 
  Child* getChild(size_t child_number) {
    return children_.at(child_number).get(); 
  } 
  size_t getNumberOfChildren() const {
    return children_.size();
  }
  void addChild(std::unique_ptr<Child> child) {
    children_.emplace_back(std::move(child));
  }
};

struct Node : Parent<Node> {
 private:
  std::string name_;
 public:
  Node(std::string name) : name_(std::move(name)) {}
  void print() const { std::cout << "Node: " << name_  << "\n";}
  void setName(const std::string& name) { name_ = name; }
  void wrong() const {
    //children_[0]->setName("Wrong"); // Not allowed
    //getChild(0)->setName("Wrong"); // Not allowed
  }
};

void printRecursive(const Node* node) {
  if (node) {
    node->print();
    for (size_t i=0; i!=node->getNumberOfChildren(); ++i)
      printRecursive(node->getChild(i)); 
  }
}

int main() {
  // Initialization
  Node root("Root");
  root.addChild(std::make_unique<Node>("Child 1"));
  root.addChild(std::make_unique<Node>("Child 2"));

  // "Computation" with pointer-to-const
  const Node* root_ptr = &root;
  printRecursive(root_ptr);
}
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/638d698db1a74ea5)

[Live demo - using composition.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59b34c8bb7f96b27)

I've used `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` in my example because I can but you may have a good reason to use `shared_ptr`.